# How to insert (merge) list into list

Tags: r

I searched SO throughout but could not find solution to this.

Here is example:

```
m1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
m2 <- data.frame(matrix(9:14, nrow = 3, ncol = 2))
mlist <- list(m1, m2)

b1 <- c(1,-1)
b2 <- c(1,-1,1)
blist <- list(b1, b2)
```

Desired result:

```
[[1]]
   X1 X2  new
1  1  3   1
2  2  4  -1

[[2]]
  X1 X2   new
1  9 12   1
2 10 13  -1
3 11 14   1
```

Comment: `lapply(seq_along(blist), function(i) { cbind(mlist[[i]], new=blist[[i]]) })` but both lists have to be the same length and in the order you want them to be in.

Comment: yes, I thought about similar solution, thought there would be better function for this rather then looping through the elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply combine `Map` and `cbind` (somewhat similar to @hrbrmstr comment I guess)

```
Map(cbind, mlist, new = blist)
# [[1]]
#   X1 X2 new
# 1  1  3   1
# 2  2  4  -1
# 
# [[2]]
#   X1 X2 new
# 1  9 12   1
# 2 10 13  -1
# 3 11 14   1
```

Comment: This is great! Thanks.

Comment: (it's still looping @Maximilian, you just don't see it this way ;-))